# How do I replace the system sounds?

Tags: 12.10, sound, system, terminal-bell

I have in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` lots of sounds for different actions. None of them are working. In System Settings --> Sound I can't choose much in configuration. Can you help me to replace those drum system sounds (log in, minimize window, log out etc.) with my own sounds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can change startup (or any other) sound in Ubuntu as follows:

What you will need: startup sound in ogg format. [You can find some ogg sound here](http://gnome-look.org/?xcontentmode=25&PHPSESSID=9c641cbc3d04a4b084c1fff5920c0692)

Browse to following paths

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/
/usr/share/sounds/
```

Look for **desktop-login.ogg** in the list. If you don’t want to hear anything at startup, delete this file.
If you want to change the sound, replace this file with your favorite track and with the same default name desktop-login. Save and close

You will need root permission to copy the file into this directory which can be done by running nautilus as root. Nautilus is a graphical application and, as such, it is better to open it with `gksu` instead of `sudo`:

```
gksu nautilus
```

Comment: Hi Avi!Thank you for your help. I have done all the things you've told me and the result is this: 1) When the login screen appears a drum heard, and 2) After I have wrote the password and then hit ENTER, at the system initialising there is no sound. Is there something else to do? Thank you.